Animations triggered by HTML events that happen to other HTML element
How do I make an animation of an icon that plays only when I hover on another Element?
I'm making a dumb project to better understand HTML, CSS and JavaScript (I'm a newbie).
I wanted to have an arrows that moves smoothly from right to left and vice versa on a loop when you hover on  a link to which it points towards.
My HTML for this part looks roughly like this:
<div class='linkHeaderDiv'>
    <a href='Something IDK.html' class='linkHeader'>Another page</a>
    <script src="Arrow Animation.js"></script>
    
    <svg class="arrowIconHeader" id="Livello_1" data-name="Livello 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 33 34">
        <defs>
            <style>
                .cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}
            </style>
        </defs>
        <line class="cls-1" x1="0.5" y1="0.5" x2="32.5" y2="17.5"/>
        <line class="cls-1" x1="0.5" y1="33.5" x2="32.5" y2="17.5"/>
    </svg>

</div>

So far I tried to use CCS to create an animation that looks like this:
@keyframes arrowTransition{
    from {transform: translateX(0%);}
    to {transform: translateX(-20%);}
}

.linkHeader:hover .arrowIconHeader{
    animation-name: arrowTransition;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-duration: infinite;
}

But I had no luck with this method, so I tried using JavaScript to write the following code:
const linkHeader = document.getElementsByClassName('linkHeader')
const arrowIconHeader = document.getElementsByClassName('arrowIconHeader')

function arrowAnimation(a) {
    a.animate(
        [{transform:'translateX(0px)'},{transform:'translateX(-20px)'}],
        {duration:2000,iterations: Infinity,}
    )
}

linkHeader.addEventListener('onmouseover',()=>{arrowAnimation(arrowIconHeader)})

But no matter what the arrow icon just won't move.

The arrow is  not moving because that element is not a child of the hovered element, but a sibling of it so you need .linkHeader:hover ~ .arrowIconHeader. Voting to close as this is essentially a missing character/typo (or a misunderstanding of how selectors work in which case a close read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors and similar pages will help).

When using getElementsByClassName it will return an array of elements, so for accessing those elements you need to either loop over returned elements or using 0th index to access the element. When we have a single element I would suggest to use id on the element and then use getElementById which will return a single element.
As per the current html you can do:
linkHeader[0].addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{arrowAnimation(arrowIconHeader)})

also on arrow animation,
a[0].animate(
  [{transform:'translateX(0px)'},{transform:'translateX(-20px)'}],
  {duration:2000,iterations: Infinity,}
)

I am not getting the animation required by you, so just make the suggestions for improvements in the js part that will animate the arrow function as per the current animate method.
